# No matching function compile error when passing lambda expression to a templated caller function?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, capture

Code:

```c++
#include <iostream>

template <class FunctorType>
void caller(const FunctorType& func) {
  func();
}

int main() {
  double data[5] = {5., 0., 0., 0., 0.};
  auto peek_data = [data]() { std::cout << data[0] << std::endl; };
  auto change_data = [data]() mutable { data[0] = 4.2; };

  caller(peek_data);    // This works
  caller(change_data);  // This doesn't
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile this with `clang++ -std=c++11 mutable_lambda.cpp`, I got
 `error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const (lambda at mutable_lambda.cpp:8:22)'`.

Question:
Why passing the second lambda expression **with mutable copy capture** failed to compile? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to figure it out yourself if you remember the fact that a lambda is just an instance of an anonymous class with an `()` operator, a `const` one by default, and a mutable one is a not-`const` one. Now take a look at what your template parameter is declared as, and see if this Scooby-Doo mystery can now be solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `mutable` lambda has a non-`const` `operator()`. You are trying to call this non-`const` `operator()` through a `const` reference. That doesn't work for the same reason that calling any non-`const` non-static member function doesn't work through a `const` reference.

---

If you want to allow `caller` to modify the passed function object (through a non-`const` `operator()` call) if it is passed as non-`const` argument, then take it by forwarding reference instead of `const` reference:

```
template <class FunctorType>
void caller(FunctorType&& func) {
  func(); // maybe std::forward<FunctorType>(func)();
}
```

---

Also note that `change_data` does not change the `data` in `main`. It changes a copy of it stored inside the lambda. If you want it to change the `data` in `main`, you need to capture `data` by-reference and then the lambda itself also doesn't need to be `mutable` anymore:

```
auto change_data = [&data]() { data[0] = 4.2; };
```

Comment: The point here is that the captured `mutable` lambda is not `const`-invocable, but the `caller` can still accept a non-capturing `mutable` lambda because it can be converted to a function pointer.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! The thing, though, is that I'm using some parallel computing library, which has a caller (say named `parallel_for`) in the same format I showed that takes in a functor and execute it in parallel. If I can't change the library, but I also need to modify data, and I have to use **copy capture** (can't use reference because CUDA doesn't support it), what do you think would be the best practice? Thanks again!

Comment: Besides, regarding your side note, I'm actually a bit surprised that it won't change `data` in `main`. Is this because `data` in `main` is in stack rather than heap?

Comment: @aaronfu I don't know anything about CUDA, but that seems like a weirdly arbitrary restriction. Anyway, you can capture a pointer to the first array element by-copy instead: `auto change_data = [data=data](){ data[0] = 4.2; };`

Comment: @aaronfu It is simply because any capture without a `&` before it captures by-copy, making a copy of the referenced entity in the closure object generated from the lambda. I don't know why stack or heap are relevant here.

Comment: Hmm I'm totally confused again.. what is the exact difference between `[data]` and `[data=data]`? I thought `[data]` means capture the address (`&data[0]`) and pass the address in by value. But are you saying that it copies the entire array instead?

Comment: @aaronfu `[data]` means capture the entity named `data` (or if that is a reference, the object it references) by-copy. `data` here is an array object, so it will create a copy of the array inside the lambda and `data` inside the lambda will refer to that array member. It does not in any way capture a pointer.

Comment: `[data=data]` is an init-capture which behaves as if by-copy capturing a variable that was initialized as `auto data=data;` except that the right-hand `data` here doesn't refer to the variable itself. The variable is considered to be the captured member of the lambda itself. Here array-to-pointer decay applies and `auto` will resolve to `double*`, so that you capture a pointer, not an array. `data` in the lambda will refer to this `double*` pointer member.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246679/discussion-between-aaronfu-and-user17732522).

Comment: Now I see! The array object thing got me. It also explains why the array allocated in the heap (e.g. by `double *data = new double[5]`) can be modified by the original lambda - because in this case it is the address rather than the entire array is copied. Many thanks!

Comment: @aaronfu Yes, but in either case you don't need the `mutable` though. You are not mutating the lambda or its subobjects itself, you are just mutating something that the lambda member points to.